# having and issue with unity and setting up a web service .cs file

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine, com

First of all i am using the most recent version of unity 5.%. 
also using Visual Studio 2013 all code is in c#

i have been following the 'tutorial' listed here

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Webservices_In_Unity

i have been following **Using ASP.NET services (.asmx)**

all my naming convention matches perfectly i have followed every step.. but i am having trouble at
 **'Consuming the service'**

i would have posted but my rank isn't high enough, to post more then one 'website link'

any who when i go to run the command prompt in the correct file
it refuses to generate the damn code.. (i can provided error codes if necessary)

so i'm curious is there a template i can follow to make my own .cs files as described in this step? or am i just missing some thing obvious..

i do realize the example is 4 years old so if that is why it wont work because how unity currently complies code or something silly like that, let me know!!.. if you know similar example to establish a web service.

I am still working on it,I will post if i come with a solution.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you get any solution or example online for same?